# Call LWC @wire method on button click

Tags: apex, lwc-wire-adapter, wire, lightning-web-components

I want to display a list of opportunities when a button is clicked. I have achieved the task using imparative Apex call but I want to do this with @wire method.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Opportunities">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button label="All" onclick={allStages}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAllStages from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getAllStages';
const COLUMNS = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type:'text'},
    {label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName', type:'text'}
];

export default class WireDemo extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;

    opps;
    errorMsg;

    allStages(){
        getAllStages()
        .then(result =>{
            this.opps = result;
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            this.errorMsg = error;
        })
    }
}
```

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityController {
   
   @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getAllStages(){
       return [SELECT Name, StageName FROM Opportunity ORDER BY Name];
    }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve the same result but using @wire method instead of imparative Apex call? I tried the following but it did not work:

```
 @wire(getAllStages)
   allStages({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.opps = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.errorMsg = error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why? Imperative makes most sense, especially when you have no parameters to pass.

Comment: This is the task requirements to use @wire method. And I also need to pass parameters at later stage.

Comment: The wire documentation will explain what you need to do. Go [read it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about).

Comment: Seems like you may have an XY problem here. Stating you have a requirement to use `@wire` makes no sense whatsoever on its face.

Comment: I read the wire documentation and it doesn't say anything about calling wire method with events like button click.

Answer (score 3):

You do not - you *cannot* - call wire adapters based on events. That's an imperative model and it's not how wire adapters work. Wire adapters are a reactive model; the system provisions new data when parameters change.

The [Lightning Web Components developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method) includes a clear description of how to use the `@wire` decorator to wire an Apex method. However, *you cannot execute the wire based on an event*. Instead, your component must accept the data provisioned by the wire at any time, and react to the event by changing its own presentation of the data (using an `if:true` directive, for example, as shown in the linked documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Made few changes to the JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAllStages from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getAllStages';

const COLUMNS = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type:'text'},
    {label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName', type:'text'}
];

export default class WireDemo extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;

    opps;
    errorMsg;
    allStages;

    @wire(getAllStages)
      allStages({ error, data }) {
      if (data) {
            this.allStages = data;
      } else if (error) {
            this.errorMsg = error;
      }
    }

    handleAllStages() {
    this.opps = this.allStages;
    }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Opportunities">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button label="All" onclick={handleAllStages}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: You are not really calling wire method on button click. You are just assigning wire method result to the variable you want on button click.

Comment: Your wired method is being called as soon as the page loads.  Add a `console.log` statement to your wired method and you'll see it run without ever clicking the button.  Your button simply causes the pre-fetched data to render.